# Target [Illuminate\View\ViewFinderInterface] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\View\Factory]

Tags: php, laravel-blade, lumen

After upgrade my app from lumen8 to lumen9 I got this error when I try to send an email with component in template.

```
[2022-12-21 12:06:40] local.ERROR: Target [Illuminate\View\ViewFinderInterface] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\View\Factory]. (View: D:\projects\blog\resources\views\emails\test.blade.php)
```

This template don't work, raise the error

```
<x-mail::message>
# Order Shipped
Your order has been shipped!
Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
</x-mail::message>
```

This template work (not as expected but work)

```
# Order Shipped
Your order has been shipped!
Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
```

there seems to be something incomplete in the documentation when migrate from lumen8.

I've tried also to create a new project with the same error.

Someone has lumen9 mail working example?

Comment: Hi, I recently encountered same error using Lumen v9. Were you able to solve the issue by any chance?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe... the `xmail::` thinks it's getting the view from another namespace. Try to extend the view if it isn't complete. The old way with @section('content') , etc

Comment: I've migrate the project to Laravel9

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue after upgrading to Lumen 9. After thoroughly examining the Laravel codebase, I found a solution. To fix this issue, add the following lines of code to `bootstrap/app.php`:

```php
$app->configure('view');
$app->alias('view', Illuminate\View\Factory::class);
```

Additionally, the final configuration should look like this:

```php
$app->configure('view');
$app->configure('mail');
$app->alias('mail.manager', Illuminate\Mail\MailManager::class);
$app->alias('mail.manager', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Factory::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue::class);
$app->alias('view', Illuminate\View\Factory::class);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've migrate to Laravel 